# How to remove stylesheet CSS file in the page and stop them from being loaded?

Tags: jquery, css

Supposing I have a CSS file named style.css and there are more of them loaded in the page. How to automatically removed them using jQuery if the file name of the stylesheet is style.css (regardless of path and URL)?

I am using this and it did not work:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="style.css"]').remove();
```

I'm doing this because I don't want them to be loaded if a certain condition is true (checked using JS). Is there other methods that you can prevent a CSS file from being loaded to the browser using jQuery?

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: it's too late to stop them with javascript, the requests are already made, need  opposite approach, only insert if conditions are right. Need more details

Comment: Yeah you have a point there..Thanks Charlietfl.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a server-side solution. Set a condition to add/omit the style tag from the code. Even if it's coming from a third party like an iFrame you can always use cURL to fetch the data and remove the style tag before sending it to the browser.

Focus on adding the style when you need it rather than removing it when you don't.

Comment: can think of conditions that aren't server related like media queries

Comment: What? You'd make a `style2.css` and override all the styles from `style1.css`? That's confusing, redundant, and inefficient.

Comment: I know what media queries do. That's not what he's asking. You have no idea what the condition would be on which he'd want to remove the style.css rules.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your `body` tag, eg: `condition1`. Make all your CSS

```
body.condition1 .something {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

do this for each of your conditions, then you can just `add` or `remove` classes with jquery according to your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) js

```
yepnope([{
  test : /* boolean(ish) - Something truthy that you want to test             */,
  yep  : /* array (of strings) | string - The things to load if test is true  */,
  nope : /* array (of strings) | string - The things to load if test is false */,
  both : /* array (of strings) | string - Load everytime (sugar)              */,
  load : /* array (of strings) | string - Load everytime (sugar)              */,
  callback : /* function ( testResult, key ) | object { key : fn }            */,
  complete : /* function                                                      */
}, ... ]);
```